# Format specifier on Double

Tags: swift, format-specifiers

I was experimenting a bit with `String`'s `init(format: String, _ arguments: CVarArgType…)` and everything was working as expected until I tried to do this :

```
String(format:"%3f", 32.6)
```

Which returned :

> 32.600000

I don't understand why it doesn't follow my desired width.

From what I know about format specifiers (I don't know them very deeply) you can specify as this :

```
%x.y
```

Where `x` is the width of the returned number (without an eventual dot) and `y` is the precision (number of digits after the dot).

So for example :

```
String(format: "%3.2", 2.1)
```

Should return :

> 2.10

And if `x` is bigger than all the digits it prepends spaces to the string.

OH. Ok I just understood. I'll just answer my own question .

Comment: @rmaddy Format specifiers are the same in C & ObjC so the tags were good to me even though my own code is Swift…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems when you don't give your format specifier a precision (the part after the dot) it will print a default number of digits (6 digits in my case).

The width I gave to my format specifier being smaller than the number representation with its digits (6 digits in default precision) it just printed the number with all the digits. If I used `%10f` it would've printed the number with prepended spaces.